# Collapsible view more and view less button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a list of 10 items to show. I want a view more button after three of those questions are displayed and upon clicking the button the rest are displayed and the view more button changes it's name to view less and the reverse. I am new to web dev and confused about how to implement this. Any help in this regard will be really helpful. Thanks.

Current code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>

<div id="demo" class="collapse"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </div>
```

Comment: Have you done something?

Comment: Yes I have looked at how to make collapsible content. but in that the view more button stays at top. I want that view more button upon clicking should move to the bottom of the list and also change it's name. This part I haven't been able to make any progress on

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
                        <div id="demo" class="collapse">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                        </div>

Comment: This is just for creating the collapible content . Don't know where to go from here

Comment: Edit your post and post the code there

Comment: @keep_it_up update your post and put your code into a snippet if possible, so that we can quickly test what you have done and give you a faster answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```js
function changeName(){
    if($("#collapseButton").html()=="View more"){
        $("#collapseButton").html("View less");
    }
    else{
        $("#collapseButton").html("View more");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div class="container">
      <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
      <p>Click on the button to toggle between showing and hiding content.</p>
      <div>
       <li>
         1
        </li>
        <li>
         2
        </li>
        <li>
         3
        </li>
      </div>
      <div id="collapsible" class="collapse">
        <li>
         4...
        </li>
        <li>
         5...
        </li>
        <li>
         6...
        </li>
        <li>
         7...
        </li>
        <li>
         8...
        </li>
        <li>
         9...
        </li>
        <li>
         10...
        </li>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div align="right">
        <button id="collapseButton" type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsible" onclick="changeName()">View more</button>
    </div>
```

you can find more details at https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp

And this code can be perfected and refactored in many ways.

Comment: this is partially what I want. I want that view more button to appear bottom of the list and upon clicking it , the list expands and the view less button appears below 10 in this case . Something like this https://news.google.com/topics/CAAqIQgKIhtDQkFTRGdvSUwyMHZNRE55YXpBU0FtVnVLQUFQAQ?hl=en-IN&gl=IN&ceid=IN%3Aen

Comment: I have edited the answer to have the button at the bottom. You can change styling and customization as per your satisfaction. I would highly suggest you go through tutorials at www.w3schools.com.